# Is it possible to exit a loop on the change of an input state?

Tags: input, loop

I would like to exit a particular loop if the state of an input changes from LOW to HIGH. This is the current loop:

```
void brakeFade() {
pixels.clear();
pixels.setBrightness(255);
pixels.fill(16711680, 0, 0);

for(int i=255; i>=10; i-=1) {
  pixels.setBrightness(i);
  pixels.show();
  delay(5);
  }
for(int j=10; j<=255; j+=1) {
  pixels.setBrightness(j);
  pixels.show();
  delay(5);
```

}
}

I need that loop to exit if

```
(digitalRead(brakeFeed) == LOW)
```

Changes to **HIGH** during the loop.

Comment: there is no reason to use two different named index variables, `i` and `j`, in the two `for` loops ... they can both be `i` .... increment can be done using `i++` instead of `i+=1` ... same with decrement

Answer (score 1):

figured it out:

```
void brakeFade2() {
pixels.clear();
pixels.setBrightness(255);
pixels.fill(16711680, 0, 0);

for(int i=255; i>=10; i-=1) {
  if (digitalRead(brakeFeed) == LOW){
  pixels.setBrightness(i);
  pixels.show();
  delay(5);
  }
  else {
    break;
  }
}
for(int j=10; j<=255; j+=1) {
  if (digitalRead(brakeFeed) == LOW){
  pixels.setBrightness(j);
  pixels.show();
  delay(5);
  }
  else {
    break;
  }
  }
```

}

Comment: simpler way would be to add it to the completion test of the `for` loop ...  `for(int i=255; (i>=10) or (digitalRead(brakeFeed) == LOW);  i--) {`

Comment: Wouldn't that be `for(int i=255; (i>=10) && (digitalRead(brakeFeed) == LOW)`? The OP wants the loop to continue as long as is >= 10, **and** the brakeFeed pin still reads as low. It should break if either of those stops being the case.